# Return or assign values to user defined record type from case statement

Tags: oracle, case

Is there a way to either return a populated record type or make the assignments as part of a CASE statement?

for example:

```
DECLARE 

    TYPE field_definition_rec    IS RECORD(FIELD        NUMBER(3),
                                           FIELD_ID     VARCHAR2(2),
                                           DEFINITION     VARCHAR2(200));
    loc_rec field_definition_rec;

BEGIN

    loc_rec := CASE
                WHEN 1 THEN  field = 1
                             field_id = 'afd',
                             definition = 'fdas'
                END CASE;

    -- OR
    CASE
        WHEN 1 THEN
            loc_rec.field = 1
             loc_rec.field_id = 'afd',
             loc_rec.definition = 'fdas'
        END CASE;
END;
```

I was hoping to use a case over an IF for simplicity sake.

Comment: The assignment operator is `:=`. The equality operator is `=`. You seem to want the assignment operator.... which is not what you're using. In this case there's no difference in complexity between `if` and `case` (or ever really). Just use an `if` statement, for simplicity's sake.

Comment: you can use PL/SQL in Oracle, see this link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm

Comment: i mean you can use CASE statement in pl/sql

Comment: So what is your actual issue ?

Comment: well the ultimate issue doesn't come down to a CASE vs IF but rather you are not able to assign all elements to a multi element record type in 1 statement like say an array

For example with the above record type

     loc_rec := (1, 'abc','xyz');

wihich is what would be necessary in a case as the THEN portion can only result in 1 action/result but in the IF, I can make all the assignments like

     loc_rec.field := 1;
     loc_rec.field_id := 'AE';
    loc_rec.definition := 'blah';